# jqgrid: add change password button and dialog

Tags: jqgrid, dialog, change-password

I'm new to jqgrid. I'm using jqgrid to show list of users. everything is OK. but
I am wanting to add a customized form in jqgrid to implement change password dialog for every rows(every users). I could add a button in the toolbar to show a dialog
[image: users grid]
and the code i used to add change password button is this:

`.navButtonAdd('#pager', {
                    caption: "Change Password",
                    title: "Change Password",
                    buttonicon: "ui-icon-changepass",
                    onClickButton: function () {
                        var selectedRowId = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                        if (selectedRowId > 0) {
                            $(this).jqGrid("editGridRow", "new");
                            var data = $("#list").jqGrid('getRowData', selectedRowId);
                            //? ...
                        }
                    },
                    position: "middle"
                })`

 Now I am wanting to customize the edit form in jqGrid so that instead of editing all features of user, I would like to implement just two input text for new password and it's confirm. something like this(designed in image editor):
[image: goal]

as you see, this dialog looks like edit dialog(the layout and appearance etc) but here I just want to change users password While in the edit dialog change every data about user.

How should I go about calling a dialog looks like edit form but just for editing the password? 
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: you can create jquery dialog with all fields you need and post url that allows you to call method on server side that changes password. Don't you want to do it that way?

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. but i don't want to do that way. a want a dialog with exactly the same appearance of edit or add dialog of jqgrid. the style, the title bar, next and previous button in the button right corner etc. that will be so hard to create my own dialog that looks exactly like jquery standard dialog.